# Point 2 domains on the same hosting to different files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having an issue with .htaccess.

I have 3 Domains in one Webspace, all directed to the same content: (www.domain1.com, www.domain2.com, www.domain3.com).

Now I want only the www.domain1.com to start with my WordPress site(index.PHP), the other two domains should start with index.HTM, but I don't want to create subfolders, because all Domains shall have access to the same .htm-Files in the root directory – ONLY the start files (index.php/index.htm) should be different. Is it possible to realize this, for example with mod_rewrite in the htaccess? I tried and failed.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain1.com

RewriteRule  ^/$ /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain2.com

RewriteRule  ^/$ /index.htm [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain3.com

RewriteRule  ^/$ /index.htm [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to my problem using PHP instead of .htaccess. It was not the neatest solution but it solves my issue:

```
  switch ($_SERVER ["HTTP_HOST"]) {
    case "www.domain1.com":
        if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL'] == '/') {
            header("Location: http://www.domain1.com/index.php");
        } else {
            header("Location: {$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL']}");
        }

        break;
    case "www.domain2.com":
        if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL'] == '/') {
            header("Location: http://www.domain2.com/index.htm");
        } else {
            header("Location: {$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL']}");
        }

        break;
    case "www.domain3.com":
        if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL'] == '/') {
            header("Location: http://www.domain3.com/index.htm");
        } else {
            header("Location: {$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URL']}");
        }

}
```